# Make a multiplication of two tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, matrix-multiplication

If you have two SQL tables and you see them like matrices, The product C of two matrices A and  B is defined as

```
c_ik = a_ij*b_jk
```

where `j` is summed over for all possible values of `i` and `k` and the notation above uses the Einstein summation convention. The implied summation over repeated indices without the presence of an explicit sum sign is called Einstein summation, and is commonly used in both matrix and tensor analysis. Therefore, in order for matrix multiplication to be defined, the dimensions of the matrices must satisfy

[image]

so

[image]

where

[image]

for example

```
a1  a2  a3
----------
14   9   4 
2   11   5 
0   12  17
5    2   3


b1   b2 
-------
12   25
 9   10
 8    5
```

is equals to

```
c1     c2 
---------
273   455
243   235
244   205
102   160
```

I was thinking in doing a While loop, but I guess there is a better way to do this
maybe using pivot or a CTE with coords of i,j,k?

```
DECLARE @count int
DECLARE @max int

SET @count int = 1
SET @max = 4

WHILE @count < @max
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO C_Table (c1, c2)
  --Do not know how to make the other products or how to get them...
   Select Sum(   (T1.Value * T2.Value)   ) 
    From A As T1
    Join B As T2
    ...
   SET @count = @count + 1
END
```

I am a little lost here...

Comment: TSQl was definitely not intended or designed for multiplying matrices!!

Comment: But could it be done? I guess it is possible, but do not know how..

Comment: Just because something can be done, doesn't mean it should be. You would be better off writing a CLR stored proc.